# su command not recognizing node service - ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

i get error while starting node service using 'su' command."command not found 'node' no such file or directory". However when i give complete path of node it works. Looks like node path is not recognizing.

```
Not working:
su test -c "node server"

Working:
su test -c "/home/test/.nvm/v4.3.1/bin/node server"
```

I tried to include -m and -p. it didnt work. any idea on how to avoid using complete path of node?

Comment: Is this Linux?  If so, put linux tag.  This is more of linux admin question.

Answer (score 0):

Softlinking it to existing PATH will do it , use the following command

```
sudo ln -s /home/test/.nvm/v4.3.1/bin/node /usr/bin/
```

Comment: actually without using 'su'  i am able to run command with both users. "test" and ''root". its only when i add su command it doesnot work. So i dont think adding link would do trick.

Comment: This is due since `/home/test/.nvm/v4.3.1/bin/` is available in root users path whereas for other users the its not available. So either you need to add the path to User or softlink to a generic Directory.

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/test/.nvm/v4.3.1/bin/` adding the following to /etc/profile, /etc/environment or .bashrc will also work. update the source if you are doing this way.

Comment: I am running command using su. so you mean i should include export and node server command in su?. like ---- **su test -c "export PATH........ ; node server"**